# Is a SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" compatible with an ASUS P8Z68-V LX?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, compatibility

The full name of the SSD is SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" 500GB SATA III 3D NAND Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) MZ-75E500B/AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are compatible - the board uses:

- USB 3.0 & SATA 6Gb/s Support
- Intel® Smart Response Technology - SSD Speed with HDD Capacity

And the Samsung SSD uses the same, you can connect it without any worry.

[image]